# Need Help with Basic Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, divisibility

So I'm having trouble setting this direct proof up. Here's the question:

Suppose for fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, we have the notation $n\mathbb{Z} + k = \{nz + k : z∈\mathbb{Z}\}$. For the rest of this question let $A = 3\mathbb{Z} + 1$ and $B = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

- Prove the following: 6 divides $(x + 2) \Rightarrow x\in A$
- Prove or disprove: 6 divides $(x + 2) \Leftrightarrow x\in A\cap x\in B$

So for the first bullet point, I know that 6 divides $x+2$ is equivalent to $x+2=6m$, however I don't know how I can show it's a member of $3\mathbb{Z}+1$ ...

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** You started well enough; from $x+2=6m$, you need to isolate $x$ and write it in a way that makes it obvious that it belongs to $3Z+1$, i.e., it is of the form $3z+1$ for some $z$ (depending on $m$).

---

**SOLUTION:**

$x+2=6m$ implies $x=6m-2$, which implies $x=3(2m)-2$, which is the same as $x=3(2m)-3+3-2=3(2m-1)+1$.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense! thank you so much!